# Using a non - US s3 server with rails, heroku and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to set this up using the article on herokus developer site.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :url => 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
  }
}
```

However all of my images are pointing to the us http://s3.amazonaws.com/ server

How can i set paperclip to use the sydney server?

UPDATE:
paperclip successfully uploads files to the sydney server, it just wrongly uses the US server rather than the sydney one when trying to view them

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip provides a [handful of options](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), to optimize the configuration of your bucket.

The ones you're interested are `url` and `s3_alias_url`.
Your configuration would look like something like this :

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
 :storage =>:s3,
 :s3_credentials => {
   :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
   :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
   :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
 },
 :url => ':s3_alias_url',
 :s3_alias_url => 's3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
}
```

You can find more information and an other example in [this google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/paperclip-plugin/gHP5u67XRS0).

Comment: Thanks Damien, looks good but it still looks for the file in the US region.

Comment: The configuration example is apparently not appropriate. See http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/ror-using-paperclip-with-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/